# How to set pixel RGB value according to image vertical strip? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, image

I have an image of 140 x 210 px that I am trying to divide into three equal vertical stripes, as follows: I need to change the red of all pixels in the left vertical third to 255, the green of all the pixels in the middle vertical to 255, and the blue of all the pixels in the right vertical third to 255. The optical effect this should have is creating a vertical red, green, and blue rainbow over the image.

I am trying to do this with the following code:

```
var image = new SimpleImage("hilton.jpg");
for (var p of image.values()) {
    if (p.getX() < 46) {
        p.setRed(255);
    }
    if (46 < p.getX() < 92) {
        p.setGreen(255);
    }
    if (p.getX() > 92) {
        p.setBlue(255);
    }
}

print(image);
```

It adds the red and blue strips just fine to the left and right of the image, respectively. But when I try to add the green strip in the middle, it messes up the whole image, i.e., it turns green the other pixels in the image as well.

I'd like to do this without any library, if possible.

Comment: Please don't use snippets if the code isn't supposed to run in the question.

Comment: Which library are you using?

PS: Never communicate via "I am REQUIRED". StackOverflow is about helping each other, not helping You pass the exam in JS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not an exam, it's just an exercise that specifies the requirements this way and I'm keen on doing it :) I'm using JS in this online editor: http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course1/example/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a small problem with your code:

```
if (46 < p.getX() < 92) {
```

is invalid syntax. That should be:

```
if (46 < p.getX() && p.getX() < 92) {
```

---

That said, without using libraries, you can only do this using an canvas, you can't just change pixels on an image:

```js
// Setup
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx= canvas.getContext("2d"),
    img = new Image(),
    w = canvas.width / 3;

// Load image
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
img.src = 'http://i190.photobucket.com/albums/z257/americanwildlife/Mammal/Z-ucumari-Valerie-redwolf.jpg';

// When the image has loaded
img.onload = function(){
    // Draw it and get it's data
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height),
        data = imgData.data;

    // Iterate over all the pixels
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
        // The current pixels' x position
        var x = Math.floor(i / 4) % canvas.width;

        //Set the pixels' r, g, b channels if x is within certain bounds.
        if(x < w)
            data[i] = 255;   // Red
        else if(x >= w && x < w * 2)
            data[i+1] = 255; // Green
        else
            data[i+2] = 255; // Blue
    }

    // Re-draw the image.
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="800px" height="639px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow, that's exactly the effect I wish to achieve. But we haven't learned to use canvases in JS yet. Hmmm...

Comment: Okay, so, does this answer your question or not?

Comment: Judging from the end result, it surely does. But I cannot understand it, as I am a beginner and the exercise is not supposed to use canvases.

Comment: Are you not supposed to understand it, or are there steps you don't quite follow? I can add some more explanation where needed, you'll just have to ask for specifics ;-)

Comment: The exercise is supposed to be solved using just basic methods such as "getX/Y()" and "setRed/Green/Blue(255)". Are you positive this is the simplest way one can do this? If you remove the middle "if" statement from my attempt from above, the red and blue strips are drawn perfectly. So I think there is rather a problem with how I modify the Green element.

Comment: Ah, there are specific function to allow image manipulation, then... Yea, now I look at your code a little better, there's an issue with it: `if (46 < p.getX() < 92) {` is invalid syntax. That should be: `if (46 < p.getX() && p.getX() < 92) {`

Comment: excellent. That did the trick! he he. Many thanks for this!!! That was the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm running through this exercise and used the <= operator instead as this ensured a crisp finish.Hope it helps.

```
    var image = new SimpleImage ("smallpanda.png");
var redLeft = image.getWidth()/1/3; 
var blueRight = (image.getWidth()/1/3)*2; 

//Red
for (var pixel of image.values()){
    if (pixel.getX() < redLeft) {
    //If the pixel’s x-coordinate is less than one-third of the image’s width, set the pixel’s red value to 255.
    pixel.setRed(255); 
    }
//Green
    if (( redLeft <= pixel.getX() ) && (pixel.getX() <= blueRight)) {
    //If the pixel’s x-coordinate is between one-third and two-thirds of the image’s width, set the pixel’s green value to 255.
    pixel.setGreen(255); 
    }
//Blue
    else{
      if (pixel.getX() > blueRight) {
    //If the pixel’s x-coordinate is more than two-thirds of the image’s width, set the pixel’s blue value to 255.
    pixel.setBlue(255); 
    }  
    }

}

print(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome posts, and definitely helped me with finishing my project as well. I basically just derived a mixture of the two:

```
var img = new SimpleImage("duvall.jpg");

for (var pixel of img.values()) {
var redLeft = img.getWidth() / 1/3; 
if (pixel.getX() <= redLeft) {
    pixel.setRed(255); 
}
var blueRight = (img.getWidth() / 1/3) * 2; 
if (pixel.getX() > blueRight) {
    pixel.setBlue(255); 
}

if (pixel.getX() >= redLeft && pixel.getX() <= blueRight) {
    pixel.setGreen(255); 
}
}

print(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ~

```
var img = new SimpleImage ("hilton.jpg");   

for (var rgb of img.values()) {
if (rgb.getX() <= img.getWidth()/3) {
    rgb.setRed(255);
    //only one-third 
}
if ((img.getWidth())/3 <= rgb.getX() && (rgb.getX() <= img.getWidth()/3*2)){
    rgb.setGreen(255);`enter code here`

 //If the pixel’s x-coordinate is between one-third and two-thirds of the 
image’s width
}
else if (rgb.getX() > img.getWidth()/3*2)
      rgb.setBlue(255);

//more than two-thirds of the image’s width
}

print (img);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = new SimpleImage("Hilton.jpg");

//Gives value of each pixel in the image
for(var pixel of img.values())
{
    //To divide the given image into 3 parts and to set pixel value to red

    if(pixel.getX()<img.getWidth()/3)
    {
        pixel.setRed(255);
    }
    //This is to set color of 3rd part of the image to Blue.
    else if(pixel.getX()>img.getWidth()*2/3)
    {
        pixel.setBlue(255);
    }
    //This is to set color of 2nd part of the image to Green.
    else if(img.getWidth()/3<=pixel.getX() && pixel.getX()<=img.getWidth()*2/3)
    {
        pixel.setGreen(255);
    }
}
print(img);
```